# JNLP arguments in IIS

Tags: java, jsp, iis, arguments, java-web-start

I have a Java web start application that receives one argument. So using a apache tomcat server and all i need to do is to create a JSP file, get the request parameter and send it to the Java application just like the code bellow:

```jsp
<%@ page contentType="application/x-java-jnlp-file" %>   
<%@ page session="true" %>   
<%   
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server 
// Getting the URL parameters from the request
final String PARAM = "docId";
String paramDocId = request.getParameter(PARAM);
%> 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="printerwebdoc.jsp?<%=PARAM + "=" + paramDocId%>">

     <information>
          <title>Web Doc Printer</title>
          <vendor>Ambisig</vendor>
          <description>Web Doc Printer</description>
     </information>

     <security>
          <all-permissions/>
     </security>

     <resources>
          <j2se version="1.6+" />
          <jar href="webdocprinter.jar" />
     </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="main.gui.Main">
        <argument><%=paramDocId%></argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

The problem is that now i need to run this application on a IIS server and the JSP doesn't work in this condition.

What can i do to pass the argument to my Java web start application using IIS?

Comment: *"..need to run this application on a IIS server and the JSP doesn't work in this condition."*  IIS supports ASP doesn't it?

Comment: I think it supports. Can i run a JNLP from a ASP file?

Comment: JNLP can be run from anything that can generate the file.  That includes JSP, PHP, ASP.. If the JNLP file does not need changing at any time, it can be pure text...

Comment: I' ve solved the problem using a ASP file. I'll post the answer here. Thank you @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrew Thompson said i used an ASP file to run my JNLP and here's the code:

```
<% 
 dim PARAM
 PARAM = "docId"
 response.ContentType="application/x-java-jnlp-file"
 dim paramDocId
 paramDocId = request.querystring("docId")
 dim ipAddress
 ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables("server_name") 
%>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://<%=ipAddress+"/Java/"%>" href="webdocprinter.asp?<%=PARAM + "=" + paramDocId%>">

     <information>
          <title>Web Doc Printer</title>
          <vendor>Ambisig</vendor>
          <description>Web Doc Printer</description>
     </information>

     <security>
          <all-permissions/>
     </security>

     <resources>
          <j2se version="1.6+" />
          <jar href="webdocprinter.jar" />
     </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="main.gui.Main">
        <argument><%=paramDocId%></argument>
   </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

With this solution i can run a receiving arguments Java Web Start application within an IIS server!

Thank you

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Is the url available publicly so I can look at it in action?

Comment: @SaeidNourian unfortunately the URL isn't public yet.

Comment: oh ok. One question then. When you click on the jnlp link in Chrome browser, does it start the webstart rightaway or does it simply download the jnlp file then you have to click on the jnlp file to start it? I'm curious to know what the effect of response.ContentType="application/x-java-jnlp-file" is.

Comment: In fact google chrome saves o jnlp file and you have to click in order to execute it. On IE and Firefox we can configure them to automatically execute the jnlp file instead of just downloading it. Do you know any workaround to chrome's problem?